# WPF print strings as lines

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

In my app I have to print some data to a printer.  This data is stored in a collection, each record in the collection has a string field and that is what is to be printed.  Each of these string fields should be one line.  I figured to do something like this

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
foreach (var x in myCollection)
{
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run(x.PrintString));
    doc.Blocks.Add(p);
}
doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "My Printing");
```

The problem is that there is an empty space after every line, something like this;

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

When I need it to look like this;

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Thanks

edit:  Add the definition of `doc`
Based on the comments I was able to it to work with the following

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
foreach (var x in myCollection)
{
    p.Inlines.Add(x.PrintString + "\r\n");
    p.Margin = new Thickness(0);
}
doc.Blocks.Add(p);
doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "My Printing");
```

Comment: What's `doc`? I would also kind of assume Paragraph would cause an empty line between. Can you add all your strings to a single paragraph? Not sure where you are getting the lines from, but double check they do not have `\r\n` tacked on at the end.

Comment: Did you try setting p.Margin and p.Padding to 0? What about adjusting p.LineHeight?

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should post the solution as an answer and not part of the question. You can accept your own answer after a few days.